# CAST written twice, in the SELECT and in the WHERE statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, casting, sql-order-by

```
SELECT CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64)
FROM customer_data.customer_purchase
ORDER BY CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64) DESC
```

This is what someone wrote, and it's working fine. Is it necessary to have `CAST` twice? Why is that so? Thank you!

I tried removing `CAST` from the `SELECT` statement, and it produced the same result. So I'm confused as to why someone would write it twice.

Comment: What is the data type of the column purchase_price? Also tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: I added the tag, thanks, I'm new here! It's a string.

Answer (score 0):

Most database support refering to column alias in the `ORDER BY` clause. So you can just alias that column, so you can then order by it:

```
SELECT CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64) purchase_price_float
FROM customer_data.customer_purchase 
ORDER BY purchase_price_float DESC
```

One might question why you need to `CAST` in the first place:

- Maybe you are storing this value as a string? If so, fixing your design should be the first goal to pursue
- On the other hand, if you already have a numeric value, you probably can use the original value to sort rather than the result of the `CAST` - which may be more efficient:

```
SELECT CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64) purchase_price_float
FROM customer_data.customer_purchase 
ORDER BY purchase_price DESC
```

---

If you are going to need this expression in several spots in your query (including the `where` clause maybe), then it would be simpler to do the computation in a subquery first:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT p.*, CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64) purchase_price_float
    FROM customer_data.customer_purchase p
) p
WHERE purchase_price_float < 10     -- filter against a numeric value
ORDER BY purchase_price_float DESC  -- sort
```

Again: this is highly inefficient; the database must `CAST` all values in the string column before it is able to filter or order by it, defeating a lot of potential optimizations (indexing, ...).

Comment: Thanks for the info on alias! The value is stored as a string, I want it to be a float so I can sort it properly. But I just do not see the need for CAST to be written twice. Can't you just use it in the WHERE statement?

Comment: *The value is stored as a string, I want it to be a float*: that would fall into the first bullet point at the end of my answer ==> Fix your data model, by storing this value as a number to start with!

Comment: *Can't you just use it in the WHERE statement*: the technique I showed works for the `order by` clause but not for the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to `cast` twice and want using the converted value in the `order by` and `where` clause, you can use a subquery :

```sql
SELECT 
  purchase_price_float
FROM
(
  SELECT CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64) purchase_price_float
  FROM customer_data.customer_purchase 
)
WHERE purchase_price_float = ..
ORDER BY purchase_price_float DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can use when you don't want to repeat casting or defining calculated column is to use UNNEST(). Cross-joinging with a flattened array with just one element will do the trick.

```sql
SELECT purchase_price_float
  FROM customer_data.customer_purchase, UNNEST([CAST(purchase_price AS FLOAT64)]) purchase_price_float
 WHERE purchase_price_float > 0
 ORDER BY purchase_price_float;
```